# display a string with multiple lines in TextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, winforms

I have a winforms application , in which I'd like to display the value of string with multiple lines in a textbox

```
 Me.txtRenseignement.Text = ""
 Dim strRensei As String() = Split(Data_RenseignementComplementaire, Environment.NewLine)
 For Each ligne In strRensei
                Me.txtRenseignement.Text &= ligne & Environment.NewLine
 Next
```

It didn't work , even I changed `Environment.NewLine` by `vbCrLf`. the **strRensei** will consider all the lines as a unique one. In the debug mode , using the text visualizer, I can see `Data_RenseignementComplementaire` has multiple lines!!!

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to set the `Multiline` property to `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TextBox.Multiline` Property

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You should change property MultiLine to true to do so :

```
txtRenseignement.Multiline = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Active multiline on textbox propertise by checking it.